# Dialog Box Input/Output assistance

Tags: java

The question is: Write a program that prompts the user to input a number. The program should output the number and a message whether the number is positive or negative or zeros.

What I have so far is this:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;

public class Problem1 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str;
    int num;

    str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a Number ");

    num = scan.nextInt();
    str = "The number is " + num;

    if (num >= 1)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str, "You have entered a positive integer", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    else if (num <= -1)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str, "You have entered a negative integer", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str, "You have entered a zero", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

I can input a number but I can't see the end result. Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
num = scan.nextInt();
```

due to the earlier line

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

scans the standard input and waits there. What you want to do is to scan `str`. Correct code would be like this:

```
str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a Number ");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(str);
num = scan.nextInt();
```

Comment: When I tried to put in your code, it says that "scan" is a duplicate. I tried changing it to console but it still wouldn't bring up the output. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @IzzyDeLeon of course you have to remove the "bad" line "Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);" You don't want to work with System.in.

Comment: I should've tried everything first before commenting. I deleted the above Scanner instead. Thank you very much!

Comment: If it works, don't forget to press the green checkmark :-) Have fun with java!